# Multiple File Upload With ProgressBar in Flash Action script with preview of image and individual progress bar for each file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, progress-bar

I am trying to develop multiple file upload script in flash action script 3.0 on
Adobe Flash CS3

And here is My Code :-  
FLASH ACTION SCRIPT :

```
import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.FileReference;

var fileRef:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
var uploadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var uploadPhotoScript:String = "http://localhost/as3/1.php";
uploadURL.url = uploadPhotoScript;


var totalFiles:int = 0;


btn_browse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onUploadClicked);

function onUploadClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
fileRef = new FileReferenceList();
fileRef.browse(new Array( new FileFilter( "Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png" )));
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectHandler);
}

function fileSelectHandler(event:Event):void {
for each(var fileToUpload:FileReference in fileRef.fileList){
        ++totalFiles;
        uploadSingleFile(fileToUpload);            
    }
}



function uploadSingleFile(file:FileReference):void {
file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onUploadProgress);
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileUploadComplete);
progressBar.width=2;
    file.upload(uploadURL);
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}

function onUploadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
  var f:FileReference = e.currentTarget as FileReference;
  var fileName:String = f.name; 
  var progres:Number = (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 100;
  progressBar1.width=3.5*(progres);
  txt_curr.text=""+fileName+"";
  prog1.text=""+progres+" %"
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
trace("upload complete");
}


function onFileUploadComplete(e:Event):void
{
--totalFiles;
  if(totalFiles == 0){
    trace("all file uploaded Successfully !");
progressBar.width=100*3.5;
  }
}
```

Where btn_browse is a button added to movie and progressBar, progressBar1 are also symbols used to show progress of all files and current file being uploaded respectively.
And txt_curr is a textbox which shows the name of current file being processed.

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$tmpfile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetfile = "images/" . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $targetfile);
}
?>
```

Now What I want is:

How can I dynamically add progress bar for each file that is selected using .browse() method ?

How can I Show Preview of each image before Uploading it to the Server?

A Delete Button If a Upload is complete?

How to display each image being uploaded along with its progress dynamically simulteniously with other files being uploded?

Can any one help me in this? I am new to flash and trying to learn it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the array of `FileReference`s, and you do not have an array of progress bars. So, to answer your questions:

To add a set of progress bars, declare a class (say a MovieClip base, but a Sprite can do), name it say `MyProgressBar`, define visuals etc, define a function that will adjust it, and add an instance of it to a set like this:

```
var myBars:Vector.<MyProgressBar>;
function fileSelectHandler(event:Event):void {
    for (var i:int=0;i<fileRef.fileList.length;i++){
        ++totalFiles;
        var myNextBar:MyProgressBar=new MyProgressBar();
        myNextBar.y=i*MyProgressBar.theHeight;
        myBarHandler.addChild(myNextBar);
        myBars.push(myNextBar);
        uploadSingleFile(fileRef.fileList[i]);            
    }
}
```

This way each element in `fileRef.fileList` will get a corresponding element in `myBars`. Then, when you parse yet another ProgressEvent, you have to get that index based on `e.target`:

```
function onUploadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var f:FileReference = e.currentTarget as FileReference;
    var i:int=fileRef.fileList.indexOf(f);
    var progressBar:MyProgressBar=myBars[i];
    var progres:Number = (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 100;
    progressBar.adjustProgress(progres); // this will alter your progress bar
}
```

Your fourth question is answered along with the first one.

About delete buttons - you should clarify what do you want to delete and from where. About previews - you can first use `FileReference.load()` method, that will load that file locally, thus enabling you to reach its contents, which you can then `addChild()` somewhere like any other file loaded from the Web.

Comment: Thanks For your Answer. but FileReference.load() doesn't works in Flash 9.0 do you have any alternative ? also can we load the response of php script like echo" File Too Large" in Flash ?